Swift HTTP Requests timing out when they shouldn't be
I am new to swift development so any advice would be nice. My HTTP requests timeout on some networks when my Kotlin app works fine. I think the URLRequest or the URLSession is what's timing out.
Apologies for my spelling...
func post(dModel: DialogModel? = nil, url: String, type: responseTypes, body: [String: Any], headers: [headerType], async: Bool = true) { //async
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let timeout: TimeInterval = 10
     
    if let url = URL(string: url) {
      var request = URLRequest(url: url)
      request.httpMethod = "POST"
      request.timeoutInterval = 30
       
      for header in headers {
        request.setValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
      }
       
      do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .prettyPrinted)
      } catch let error {
        self.processError(dModel: dModel, error: error.localizedDescription, type: .report)
        return
      }
      let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
      sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0
      sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0
       
      URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        .dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
          self.processError(dModel: dModel, error: error.localizedDescription, type: .report)
           
          if(async){
            semaphore.signal() // Signal semaphore even in case of error
          }
           
          return
        }
         
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
          if let unWrappedData = data {
            if let httpResponseData = String(data: unWrappedData, encoding: .utf8) {
              self.parse(dModel: dModel, type: type, response: httpResponseData, statusCode: httpResponse.statusCode)
            }
          }
        } else {
          self.processError(error: "Invalid response")
        }
         
        if(async){
          semaphore.signal() // Signal semaphore after processing the response
        }
      }
      .resume()
       
      if(async){
        semaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + timeout)
      }
    } else {
      processError(error: "Invalid URL")
    }
  }

Here is another place with the same behaviour.
class HasInternet: ObservableObject {
  let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
  let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")
  private var status: NWPath.Status = .requiresConnection
  @Published var isConnected = false
  init(){
    monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
        if let url = URL(string: "https://google.com") {
          var request = URLRequest(url: url)
          request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
          request.timeoutInterval = 30
          let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
          sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0
          sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0
          URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
            .dataTask(with: request) { (_, response, error) -> Void in
              guard error == nil else {
                return
              }
              guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?
                .statusCode == 200 else { return }
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.isConnected = true
              }
            }
            .resume()
        }
    }
    monitor.start(queue: queue)
  }

}


The HTTP request should be going through and returning perfectly...

This question is similar to: Timeout when offline iOS (using waitsForConnectivity). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you can avoid giving timeout interval it will take default interval 180
and you can add url like below
 let urlString = request.path.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString!)!)

